# A parent who has more than one child with one or more partners: "Poly-what?"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, kinship-terms

A *[polyglot](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/polyglot)* is someone who can speak many languages; something that is *[polychromatic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/polychromatic)* has many colours, and [polysemy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/polysemy) is a word or phrase with multiple meanings

If *[polygamy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/polygamy)* is  having  more than one wife or husband  at the same time, but a *[polygynist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polygynist)* refers only to a man who has many wives. If  *[polyandry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/polyandry)* is having more than one husband and a [polygamist](http://findwords.info/term/polygamist) is usually a man who has more than one wife at the same time.

What do you call a "multiple father" or "multiple mother", someone who has more than one child with the same partner? And what do you call a parent who has two or more children with two or more different partners?

Comment: Polyamory might work

Comment: How 'bout a *polyprogenist*?  from *poly-* "many" + *progeny* "children" ;-)

Comment: You might be looking for [*group marriage*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_marriage) and it is a form of _polyamory_.

Comment: I think Bill Cosby says that until you have more than one child you're not a "**real parent**" because with only one, you always know who did it.

Comment: You call the parent a *parent*. Their children who share only one parent in common are half-siblings, of course.

Comment: It sounds ridiculous, but logically, someone who has more than one child ought to be _polytecnic_ (from Greek _τέκνον_ ‘child, son’, unlike _polytechnic_, which is from Greek _τέχνη_ ‘skill, art, craft’). If you want the single/multiple partner bit as well, you're looking at rather horrible compounds like _polyhomogamotecnic_ and _polypolygamotecnic_ or something like that. Most off-putting. (It seems the Modern Greek word for someone who has many children is actually _πολυτέκνος_!)

Comment: @AndrewLeach I know about half-brothers/sisters, stepparents and the like, I was curious if a poly— term existed. It seems odd that it doesn't.

Comment: Multiple parent: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=multiple+parenthood%2C+multiple+parent+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmultiple%20parenthood%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmultiple%20parent%3B%2Cc0. Multi-parent Law.http://abcnews.go.com/Health/GMAHealth/california-considers-bill-multiple-legal-parents/story?id=16705628

Comment: There may just not be a good term for it. The children from one parent and multiple 'spouses' are half-siblings. The non-parental spouse is a step-parent. But for the center person (the one with many spouses and children from each one), there's no special label for that person.

Comment: So you mean that not all of one’s children share the same biological parents, right?

Comment: It appears that the definitions of multiplicity are used from the point of view of the children rather than that of the parents. A father or a mother with sons from different partners are still called  fathers and mothers. Children with more than one father or one mother are cases of multiple  parenthood. " ... law to investigate surrogate motherhood and multiple parenthood families." http://www.government.nl/news/2013/11/19/senate-approves-lesbian-parenthood.html

Comment: @tchrist two parents who have let's say ten kids between them. One term for a parent who has children from the same partner; a different term for a parent who has children from multiple partners. A "multiple mother and/or father" is the nearest I could get. Is there no poly___ expression?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Probly not in English yet. Yet -- give "Modern Family" another generation and there might be. But there are too many possible variations for a simple_poly_- compound to stand for everything one might want to represent. Isn't that always the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest *poly-word* that I found which has documented usage is the following: **polyphiloprogenitive**

> **Meaning**:
>   adjective: Extremely prolific.
>
> **Etymology**:
>   From Greek *poly-* (many) + *philo-* (loving) + Latin *progenitive* (producing offspring), from *pro-* (toward) + past participle of *gignere* (to beget). Earliest documented use: 1919, in a poem by T.S. Eliot.
>
> **Usage**:
>   "*Polyphiloprogenitive Joe Fallon, the needy, **breedy father of seventeen**, or was it nineteen? I was never sure, any more than Joe himself*."
>   <sub>Aidan Higgins; Dog Days; Secker & Warburg; 1998.</sub>
>
> "*All spring and summer my parents ricochet from garden to garden, mulching, watering, pulling up the polyphiloprogenitive weeds, 'until', my mother says, 'I'm bent over like a coat hanger*."
>   <sub>Margaret Atwood; Bluebeard's Egg; McClelland & Stewart; 1983.</sub>

Alternatively the Latin term **philoprogenitive**

> 1. producing offspring, especially abundantly; prolific.
> 2. of, relating to, or characterized by love for offspring, especially one's own.
>      1860-65; *philo-* + *progenitive*

Sources: [A.Word.A.Day](http://www.wordsmith.org/words/polyphiloprogenitive.html); [Phrontistery](http://phrontistery.info/p.html); [*Worthless Word For The Day*](http://home.comcast.net/~wwftd/pq.htm#polyphiloprogenitive) aka WWFTD; [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polyphiloprogenitive), [Random House Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/philoprogenitive) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polyphiloprogenitive)

Comment: +1 for usage example, yuck for it being a mutant helleno-romantic. and if that's not a word yet, it should be.

Comment: -1 Sorry, but that is not the word that answers your question. I considered answering with both _philoprogenitive_ and T.S.Eliots 'nonce' word _polyphiloprogenitive_ but didn't because they both only mean _prolific_, neither meets the question's criteria for a word meaning _bearing children with multiple partners_.

Comment: @Frank you should have posted it as an answer, I would have awarded it as being the closest  and good-enough answer. At least it is well-documented, and it's more pronounceable than ScotM's "nonce" suggestion. Did you remember to downvote all the other answers posted too for not answering the question? I guess not...

Comment: No, I didn't downvote the other questions because they made an attempt to come up with a word that fitted your question as it originally was, now the question if much simpler _parent with more than child_ you could have _polyparous_, _polytocous_ or _polycarpous_.

Comment: When I downvoted your answer I hadn't noticed that you'd changed the question to one where the word _prolific_ (in the sense of breeding) is a suitable word so _polyphiloprogenitive_ is a reasonable answer to the edited question, so I would reverse my downvote if I could, but I am prevented from doing so by the system until the answer is edited.

Comment: @Frank  Erm.... *A parent who has more than one child with one or more partners* The title has always been that. All the answers posted mention "many children". I did not change the question, I reworded the last line from *And what do you call a parent who has **more than one child**  with multiple  partners?* TO "*And what do you call a parent who **has two or more children** with two or more different partners?* More than one child = two children. Oh, you're right the question is completely changed.

Comment: The title wasn't that when I added my first comment about _polygyny_, but  it's clear I haven't paid enough attention to your edits and for that I apologise. I have reread the question carefully and as I said I will happily reverse my downvote if the system would allow me to do so.

Comment: @Frank But you downvoted  my answer which I posted **17 hours ago**! Your explanatory comment was posted 10 hours ago. The title was modified **two days ago**. I am the OP for Christ's sake. I get to choose who has answered MY question. Try reversing your downvote on the OP itself. (There are two; one, I guess could be yours.)

Comment: I didn't downvote your question so I can't reverse it. As I said, I clearly didn't pay enough attention to the edits you made to the question. I almost always add a comment when downvoting so that the answerer can respond and perhaps clarify why the downvote may be unjust - as you have done in this case.

Comment: On the off-chance the user Frank deletes his original comment, and a casual reader can make head nor tail of the discussion I quote verbatim *"-1 Sorry, but that is not the word that answers your question. I considered answering with both philoprogenitive and T.S.Eliots 'nonce' word polyphiloprogenitive but didn't because they both only mean prolific, neither meets the question's criteria for a word meaning bearing children with multiple partners."*

Answer (score 12):

Though I am disgusted at the Greek-Latin lexical miscegenation, a parent of multiple children is ***polyprogenitive***, from the Latin prōgeniēs, 'to beget'.  From *[The Embodied Female](https://books.google.com/books?id=hx6QnP9q_DkC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=polyprogenitive&source=bl&ots=9hFu2rMFBq&sig=eD9EOllJihz2Jx8J1-AYSHOIp9E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UXkJVZKGLIP38QW7xIH4Cw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=polyprogenitive&f=false)*:

> Co-wives and surrogacy exist since Biblical times. For instance, resenting the four sons her fertile sister “gave” their common husband Jacob, barren Rachel gives him her maid Bilhah as surrogate, and adopts the two sons by this union. Emotions driving these transactions are unaccounted by Freudian chains of phallocentric symbolic equations slip-sliding between baby = penis or Darwinian notions of **polyprogenitive** male desire to spread his sperm. Neither can egg-exchange be entirely construed by Kleinian gynaecratic accounts of reparative urges to undo unconscious phantasies of raiding the archaic mother's envied fertile body for the babies within.

Technically, and although it doesn't fit the *poly-* mold requested, a person with more than one child would be ***multiprogenic*** (or *[multi-progenic](http://www.jasna.org/persuasions/on-line/vol30no1/dabundo.html)*).  (The Greek equivalent, as Janus [pointed out](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233941/a-parent-who-has-more-than-one-child-with-one-or-more-partners-poly-what#comment503260_233941), is *polytecnic*, from τέκνον meaning 'child, son'.)

Similarly, a person who has children with multiple partners, [according to social scientists](http://www.guttmacher.org/pubs/journals/3918107.html), practices ***multipartnered*** fertility.

Comment: I like this answer, If I hadn't honed in on the Greek, I might have gone the Latin route: multiparty-progenic ;-)

Comment: *polytecnic* is too similar to *polytechnic*, not your fault, I know. I did like the "multipartnered fertility" expression, and I think I'll be using that in future.

Comment: I think it's a little unfair that you now add *polyprogenitive* after I "discovered" *polyphiloprogenetive* they are practically identical: Your original answer had "polytecnic"; "multiprogenic" and "multipartnered fertiliyty

Comment: I think it's a little unfair to now tag on *polyprogenetive* in your answer, after I posted  *polyphiloprogenetive*, they are virtually the same (mine has "love" though!). This now makes it your fourth suggestion: 1) *polytecnic*; 2) *multiprogenic*; 3) multipartnered fertility; and now *polyprogenetive*. tsk, tsk, I said no more than three! ;). If you had posted this polyprothingy earlier, I wouldn't have scoured interminable lists of poly-words today. The green tick goes to me!

Comment: I do nevertheless I like your answer. :)))

Comment: i admit you gave me the idea for even considering greek-latin hybrids; that thought hadn't crossed my mind until you posted your answer.  but i was entirely surprised you hadn't answered with *polyprogenitive* after your scouring.  *polyphiloprogenitive* seems hyperbolic to me (while i enjoy these types of words, the subtleties introduced aren't appropriate for a generic term).

Comment: I listed the poly-words I knew, I triple-checked their definitions before posting. I guessed *polychromatic* and it came up! The serious scouring I did yesterday :)

Comment: No dictionary I've checked considers 'polyprogenitive' idiomatic enough to be considered part of the lexicon.

Answer (score 4):

.

In the simple case, a couple stayed married and had lots of kids (back when there was little else to do for fun, and no reliable means of contraception) there was no need to have a word for father or mother of a large family, as it was not unusual.  Even now, this is the norm in some areas of society (Catholics and Mormons are stereotypical examples). A married woman who gets pregnant as often as possible is referred to as **barefoot and pregnant** or  sometimes a [baby factory](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=baby%20factory) or a **breeder**. These are all derogatory.

In traditional terms, when monogamy, cohabitation and marriage were assumed, serial partnerings resulted in **step-fathers**, **step-mothers**, **half-brothers** and **half-sisters**.

Outside of that paradigm of matrimony, nomenclature gets a bit cloudy (although half-brother and half-sister are still accurate).
 note: There's a certain amount of inherent asymmetry, in that you can't always prove who is the biological father (or used to couldn't) but there is rarely any doubt as to who is the biological mother.

If one woman has children by different fathers whom she did not marry, and does not live with, those men are [baby daddies](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=baby%20daddy&defid=104825) to their respective offspring, regardless of the number of children.

If one man fathers children by different mothers whom he did not marry, and does not live with, those women are **baby mommas** to his offspring, regardless of number of children.

If a man sires many children, each with a different baby momma, I would call him a **seed-sower** (i.e., he has been **sowing wild oats**.)
[Origin of phrase "sow wild oats"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79648/origin-of-phrase-sow-wild-oats)

If a woman bears many children, each conceived with a different baby daddy, you could call her a "serial baby momma". (That's derogatory, but not so derogatory as "slut". Of course, a [slut/ ho/ promiscuous woman/ sexually active female] might have lots of partners but no babies)

If a "baby daddy" disappears (whether by his choice or that of the baby momma), and plays no part in bringing up his offspring,  he becomes what was once called an **absentee father**. Such a man is in legal terms a **biological father**, or colloquially, **biological dad** (sometimes more bluntly referred to as a **sperm donor**.) If the state keeps up with him and can keep him paying child support, he is a child-support payer. If not, he is a **deadbeat dad**.

If a man maintains a **polygynous** household, where multiple children born of several different wives are raised as his own, he is the **patriarch** of that family. Brigham Young, for example, was such a patriarch. (**polygamy** is no longer legal, nor sanctioned by the LDS church, but a few isolated splinter groups still practice it.)

I don't know of similar examples from **polyandry**, but I suppose by parallelism that the one mother in a polyandrous household with multiple husbands would be called the **matriarch**.

Comment: +1 This is a good useful answer, I have already heard of the terms *baby daddies* and *baby mommas* but never *child-support payer*. Could you highlight these terms in bold, please?  I am however looking for a more formal term, and I'm not 100% certain a BrEng speaker would know what *baby momma/mum/mamma* or *baby daddies* are. I suppose I could use the AmEng and then explain that.... I strongly dislike *serial baby momma* it sounds very derogative, and I would not use it.

Comment: Interestingly the term [*baby factory*](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2014/aug/23/interpol-japanese-baby-factory-man-fathered-16-children) can also be referred to a man who "makes" babies.

Comment: @mari-lou is not "baby factory" referring to the house that was raided?

Comment: @erich I suppose so, but it is "run" by the *father*, although there are "nannies" looking after his off spring.

Answer (score 3):

With a single partner, either a **man** or a **woman** could be called a
*polypedonist*, or more succinctly, *polypedist*:

> From ancient Greek:
>
> - πολύ (poly) = *many*
> - παιδίον (paidion) = small child under training
> - -ιστής (-istes) = active agent
>
> *One with many children.*

*[Pedo-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pedo&searchmode=none)* is the English root used in *pediatrics* and and *pedophile*, from the masculine παις, son, and the neuter παιδόν, including both male and female children. With the suffix *-ist*, the final *o* is normally dropped, but adding the *n* to form *pedon-* or adding an *a* to form *paed-* would both disambiguate from the *ped* of *foot*. From [etymonline:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pedo&searchmode=none)

> before vowels ped-, word-forming element meaning "boy, child," from
> Greek pedo-, comb. form of pais "boy, child," especially a son, from
> PIE root *peu- "small, little, few, young" (see few (adj.)). The
> British form paed- is better because it avoids confusion with ped-.

With **multiple** partners, either a **man** or a *woman* could be called a *polykoinoteknist*:

> From ancient Greek:
>
> - πολύ (poly) = *many*
> - κοινός (koinos) = shared in common
> - τέκνον (teknon) = offspring
> - -ιστής (-istes) = active agent
>
> *One with many shared offspring.*

The word παιδόν carried deeper connotations of *ongoing nurture*, while τέκνον generally referred to the physical offspring of any creature. If one really wanted to tweak the multi-partner arrangement, the designation could be altered to *polykoitoteknist*:

> From ancient Greek:
>
> - πολύ (poly) = *many*
> - κοιτός (koitos) = marriage bed
> - τέκνον (teknon) = offspring
> - -ιστής (-istes) = active agent
>
> *One with many bedded offspring.*

Comment: Are those real words?  A Google search shows nothing for either one.

Comment: I know this is an English *language* site, and I did ask for a "poly" word, but I don't know any ancient Greek at all. I tried looking up *paidon*, the nearest I found was [pais](http://biblehub.com/greek/3816.htm). Is *paidon* plural form?

Comment: Just to confirm *koine* is syllabified as koi·ne. The Italian in me is tempted to say ko.in.e

Comment: @Mari _Paidon_ isn't really a form at all, but _paido-_ is the inflectional stem of _pais_, and Greek sometimes inserts extra n’s in compounds and desinences here and there. Here, I'd say _polyp(a)edist_ instead, though, and I'd say the second one would be _polykoinoteknist_ (or _polykoinotecnist_), too. And yes, _koine_ is only two syllables.

Comment: There isn't any poly- word that covers my request, is there?  The ones you've proposed are also a bit of a mouthful :) However, I asked for a poly-word, I did not ask for an equivalent formal term (hindsight is wonderful) so I've decided, The green tick is yours.

Comment: I’m still not sure where you’re getting this neuter _παιδόν_ from … do you mean the diminutive _παιδίον_ (which is neuter)? _Παιδόν_ is not in LSJ or any other dictionary in the Perseus library, nor can I find any references to it anywhere online. _Παῖς_, of course, is grammatically masculine, but refers to children of either gender.

Comment: I found something better. Sorry!

Comment: It is παιδίον, not παιδόν. Although παῖς seems to have originally referred to just boys, it did expand to include girls too. This answer seems to be an interesting exercise in word-smithing, but *polyprogenic* is the direct Greek solution. Kudos for the play on κοινός and κοιτός.

Comment: If 'polypedonist' and 'polykoitoteknist' are in the English lexis, your answer should provide linked and attributed supporting references. If it's a D-I-Y candidate, the above has no place on ELU.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth—ever the staunch unbending traditionalist. Our culture is crafting new words daily without your permission, and as mainstream members of our culture, we are fully qualified to recommend candidates here or in any other public forum. Every candidate I recommended was formulated from recognizable stems and affixes found in the English lexis.

Comment: I take it you haven't read the ELUMeta thread whose anti-unsupported-candidate (whoops) (but not used in an 'answer') stance is quite clearly spelled out?

Answer (score 0):

I would leverage polyphiloprogenitive, given in Mari-Lou's answer. But regarding the concern that it doesn't address the multiple reproductive partners, I would coin **polyamoroprogenitive**.

This combines *polyamorous*

> The practice, state or ability of having more than one sexual loving relationship at the same time, with the full knowledge and consent of all partners involved. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyamory))

and *progenitive*

> capable of having offspring; reproductive ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/progenitive))

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the proffered **polyphiloprogenitive** satisfies both the "multiple partners" (poly **philo**) and the "multiple offspring" parts of the original question, without needing to stray into *amor*.

If one insists on purity-of-lexicon and is content to stay with Greek, then the term **polyphiloteknic** works perfectly. The **k** helps to distinguish the "offspring" part from the homophonic *technic*.